# iCheck and jQuery serialize

Tags: jquery, icheck

I use the iCheck plugin to beautify my checkboxes. However, when I gather all filled in data from the form with jQuery serialize, the checked checkboxes are not seen or submitted by post.

I guess that when a user clicks the iCheck box to be checked, the state of the input type checkbox is not actually set to the checked state.

How to do this? Using normal HTML checkboxes are picked up fine by serialize.

Relevant part of the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="">
<input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="remote" name="remote" value="1">
</label>                        
</div>
```

Script:

```
//iCheck for checkbox and radio inputs
$('input[type="checkbox"].minimal, input[type="radio"].minimal').iCheck({
checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue',
checkedClass: 'checked',
});
```

Submitting function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/taken/action.php',
  data: $form.serialize(),
  dataType: "json",
  ............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that iCheck wraps the check box in a div like this :

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false">
    <input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-1" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
</div>
```

When you check it it adds the checked class you specified, in this case 'checked', to the div.

What I would do is simply to have hidden inputs that you change the value when you click on the div:

```
$(".icheckbox_minimal").click(function(){
    // You might want more logic in here since You probably have more then
    // One check box to toggle.
    var val = $("#myHiddenIpnut").val();
    $("#myHiddenIpnut").val(val === "true" ? "false" : "true");
});
```

Now jQuery will grab these inputs :)

Comment: Thanks, that put me in the right way. Made a hidden field, and used callback function of iCheck to change it.

$('#onsitecheckbox').on('ifChecked', function(event){
        alert(event.type + ' callback');
        $("#location").val('onsite');
      });
      
      $('#onsitecheckbox').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
        alert(event.type + ' callback');
        $("#location").val('remote');
      });

Comment: @Mbrouwer88 Good to know :)